# Where did Mars' water go?

Tags: mars, water

Many sources indicate that there is [ice water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_polar_ice_caps) on [Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars) today, but it is mainly [traces](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Mars_Express/Water_ice_in_crater_at_Martian_north_pole), here and there, but not that much.

However, solid hypothesis state that there were oceans on Mars, see Wikipedia's [Mars ocean hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_ocean_hypothesis) or at least [large aquifers on early Mars](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Results_from_Mars_Express_and_Huygens/Mars_Express_evidence_for_large_aquifers_on_early_Mars). They all concern early Mars so around 3.5 to 4 billions years ago. These theories suggest that Mars oceans could have formed Mesa landscapes (just like[Grand Canyon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canyon) or [Monument Valley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_Valley)).

So my question is simple, if all these hypotheses are true, where did that water go?

Is it possible that so much water could have been evacuated from the planet? I guess it would have needed A LOT of energy.

So it may have been transformed on the planet.

Is it possible that the water has oxidized iron, creating Iron oxide (ie rust) and that it is the main reason for Mars red color?
The Mars ocean hypothesis page suggests some leads about the [fate of that ocean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_ocean_hypothesis#Fate_of_the_ocean), but none suggests the oxidation of iron consuming the entire oceans. Moreover, oxidation would imply the presence of water and dioxygen...

[image]
http://en.yibada.com/articles/18182/20150309/red-planet-once-held-large-shallow-ocean-mean-positive-signs.htm

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32484/16685

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the water evaporated, some of it froze and another good part of it went into the surface and is now subterranean. For more info read [Mars' Vanished Water & Atmosphere --Where Did It Go?](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2011/08/-mars-vanished-water-atmosphere-where-did-it-go.html) and [MAVEN’s Quest – Where Did Mars Water Go?](http://www.universetoday.com/106297/mavens-quest-where-did-mars-water-go/).

There's much still to learn and experiments in the future will help us to better understand the evolution of Mars' atmosphere.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by evaporated.   Water evaporates on Earth in vast amounts every day but Earth doesn't lose much water.      There's two primary mechanisms through which Mars lost it's water.   Jeans escape and being blown off by the solar wind.

Comment: @userLTK thats an answer. Chop Chop

Comment: If the water evaporated or went in to space, where did the atoms of the water molecules eventually go? Mass doesn’t disappear so did these hydrogen and oxygen atoms eventually become comets? Make there to another planet, etc?