# Is there permanent dry ice on Mars?

Tags: mars

Are there any places featuring permanent dry ice (carbon dioxide ice) on Mars?

Is there dry ice at the poles?

Comment: Also related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32484/16685 That question is mostly about Martian water, but I do briefly mention CO2 ice in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

The Southern polar ice cap has a covering of $\mathrm{CO_2}$ about 8 m thick that doesn't completely disappear in summer. It remains in "pits" of up to about 1km in diameter.  The  thinner dry ice layer in the North sublimes completely into the atmosphere in summer. [[source]](https://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/M/Marspoles.html)

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! How thick is the covering in the summer? I guess its 8m in the winter so its thinner in the summer

Comment: Does it mean South pole don't have water ice?